# Solution in $\mathbb{N}$ of an equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have to solve in $\mathbb{N}$ the following:

$$3n - 14m = 2$$

So basically this means $$n = \dfrac{2}{3}(7m+1)$$

which means I need $7m - 1$ do be a multiple of $3$. For example, it happens when $m = 2$ and $m = 5$ and basically for $m = 3k-1$ for $k = 1, 2, \cdots$. I have found this by a hand trying, nothing else.

Is there any way to "solve it better" or have I to get settled with this only?

Comment: Hint : Bezout's identity

Comment: Hint: your equation is equivalent to $3n-14m=3(-4)+14.$ Group the two $3$'s on the LHS and the two $14$'s on the RHS and use coprimality.

Comment: $3n-14m=2\implies 3n=14m+2\implies n=\frac{2}{3}(7m+1)$

Comment: @DanielMathias lol right, I completely messed up. Corrected, and thanks!

Comment: You can find the general solution in any book of introductory/basic Number Theory.

Comment: $\!\bmod 3\!:\ 2 \equiv -14m\equiv m,\,$ so $\,m = 2+3k,\,$ so $\,n = \overbrace{(2+14(2+3k))/3}^{\textstyle(2+14m)/3} = 10+14k.\,$ See the linked dupe (and its links) for other methods and worked examples.

Answer (score -1):

Since the greatest common divisor of $2$ and $3$ is $1$, then $$\frac{2(7m-1)}{3}\in\mathbb{Z}\Longleftrightarrow \frac{7m-1}{3}\in\mathbb{Z}\Longleftrightarrow$$$7m-1$ is a mutiple of $3$.

Then we note that for a given integer $m_0$ ,
$7m_0-1$ is a multiple of $3\Longleftrightarrow$ for all integer $k$, $7(3k+m_0)-1$ is a multiple of $3$,
which uses the fact that $1$ is the greatest common divisor of $7$ and $3$. So we conclude that the solutions of $m$ must be the unions of several sets $\{3i+k| k$  is a fixed integer $\}$. Then it remains to check if $m=1,2,3$ works, because the set$\{3i+k_1\}$ and $\{3i+k_2\}$ are the same if $k_1-k_2$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque Well, but you should note that I wrote my answer before it was labeled duplicate.

Comment: That's no excuse - it should be clear that a question so basic has been already answered *many times* on a site more than 12 years old.

Comment: @BillDubuque Fine, what about posting comments under the question? Please tell me if this is allowed.